# How to get biggest BigDecimal value

Tags: java, math, bigdecimal

How can I get the largest possible value of a BigDecimal variable can hold? (Preferably programmatically, but hardcoding would be ok too)

**EDIT**
OK, just realized there is no such thing since BigDecimal is arbitrary precision. So I ended up with this, which is sufficiently big for my purpose:
`BigDecimal my = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.MAX_VALUE)`

Comment: You need alot of memory to start with. ;)

Comment: @Peter that means there is no such constant value since BigDecimal is arbitrary precision, right?

Comment: @LAS_VEGAS Correct, there's just no such thing. You have to pick a limit and say that's the most you want to support.

Comment: By the way, you probably also want to define the smallest (positive) number that you allow, to limit the number of digits stored per number to a reasonable memory footprint.

Comment: The largest value BigDecimal can represent requires 8 GB of memory.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Its an arbitrary precision class, it will get as large as you'd like until your computer runs out of memory.

Comment: Not true, it is limited to Integer.MAX_VALUE words.

Comment: Andre, can you explain or give link ? What do you mean by  "it is limited to Integer.MAX_VALUE words" ? Thanks

Comment: @Adio, it stores the number using an array of ints. In Java, arrays are indexed by ints, so can have at most Integer.MAX_VALUE entries. So the largest possible BigInteger consumes roughly 8GB of RAM (4 bytes an int * 2GB entries). In a 64-bit JVM, the heap size could be many times that, so available memory is not always the limiting factor to the largest possible BigInteger or BigDecimal.

Comment: Hello. I think it requires 8GB of RAM: 2^31-1 (Integer.MAX_VALUE) * 4 bytes (size of integer) = 8589934588 bytes ~= 8GB

Answer (score 14):

Looking at the source BigDecimal stores it as a BigInteger with a radix,

```
private BigInteger intVal;
private int scale;
```

and from BigInteger

```
/** All integers are stored in 2's-complement form.
63:    * If words == null, the ival is the value of this BigInteger.
64:    * Otherwise, the first ival elements of words make the value
65:    * of this BigInteger, stored in little-endian order, 2's-complement form. */
66:   private transient int ival;
67:   private transient int[] words;
```

So the Largest BigDecimal would be,

```
ival = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
words = new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE]; 
scale = 0;
```

You can figure out how to set that. :P

**[Edit]** So just to calculate that,
In binary that's,

(2^35)-2 1's (I think?)

in 2's complement

01111111111111111...until your RAM fills up.

Answer (score 13):

Given enough RAM, the value is approximately:

2<sup>2<sup>40</sup></sup>*10<sup>2<sup>32</sup></sup>

(It's definitely out by a few orders of magnitude but in relative terms it's a very precise estimate.)

Comment: May I ask how you came to that value?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea, It definitely started with this definition: `The value of the number represented by the BigDecimal is therefore (unscaledValue × 10-scale).`, but I think I calculated with a `byte` backing array for the `BigInteger` storing the unscaled value, instead of an `int`, so I've "slightly" undershot the real limit.

Answer (score 10):

You can represent 2^2147483647-1 however after this value some methods do not work as expected. It has 646456993 digits.

```
System.out.println(BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                                 .subtract(BigInteger.ONE).bitLength());
```

prints

```
2147483647
```

however

```
System.out.println(BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(Integer.MAX_VALUE).bitLength());
```

prints

```
-2147483648
```

as there is an overflow in the number of bits.

BigDecimal.MAX_VALUE is large enough that you shouldn't need to check for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can store Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 integers in the magnitude, because arrays count from zero. All those integers got 32 bits, because they're all handled unsigned. So the precision in bits is
32*2147483648 = 68719476736 Bits (=8589934592Byte=8GiB=8,6GB). 
To get the precision in Decimals, you'll have to multiply the precision in Bits with log10(2) so you'll get 20686623783 full decimal digits, way over 4 times more, than a String can store.
Now you can pow 10 with this amount of digits and subtract 1 to get the maximal BigDecimal value, but don't try to calculate it with BigDecimal itself. ;)

But now the question is... What comes first? The method .precision(), which is limited to Integer.MAX_VALUE or my calculated precision?

Comment: If you can store ```Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1``` entries in an array, what would be the length of the array? The length an integer attribute stored with the array so it can't be mor than ```Integer.MAX_VALUE```.