# What are the limits of the decimal type in XML Schema (XSD)?

Tags: xml, xsd, decimal, xsd-validation, xml-validation

What are the minimum and maximum acceptable values of the decimal type in XML Schema? (`type="xs:decimal"`)?

Comment: Seems it's up to your definition of the constraints: [datatype decimal](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-2-20010502/#decimal)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**XML Schema itself does not impose minimum and maximum values on [`xsd:decimal`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-2-20010502/#decimal):**

> [Definition:]  decimal represents arbitrary precision decimal numbers.
>   The ·value space· of decimal is the set of the values i × 10^-n, where
>   i and n are integers such that n >= 0.

[Contrast this with [**`xsd:float`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-2-20010502/#float), which corresponds to IEEE single-precision 32-bit floats.]

**Implementations, on the other hand, may support limits to the range of `xsd:decimal`:**

> NOTE: All ·minimally conforming· processors ·must· support decimal
>   numbers with a minimum of 18 decimal digits (i.e., with a
>   ·totalDigits· of 18). However, ·minimally conforming· processors ·may·
>   set an application-defined limit on the maximum number of decimal
>   digits they are prepared to support, in which case that
>   application-defined maximum number ·must· be clearly documented.

[For example, Xerces2-J [uses](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xs/org/apache/xerces/xs/datatypes/XSDecimal.html#getBigDecimal()) `java.math.BigDecimal`; see [How to get biggest BigDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791970/how-to-get-biggest-bigdecimal-value) value for answers on how big BigDecimal can be.]